# Error with AOT compilation when using a static method ModuleWithProviders override

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

*Please suggest a better title if you can think of one*

We have a multi-module enterprise application that is written in Angular 2

To handle multi-customer use of our system we have an override strategy for images and such. Basically a map of strings to file locations. To switch which assets get overridden we pass the map to override the existing map into the `.forAssets()` method below. This pattern was taken from the Angular 2 `RouterModule` source code.

This issue is when AOT compiling we get the error

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol MainModule in /Users/--/--/my-module/index.ts, resolving symbol MainModule in /Users/--/--/common-module/index.ts

#### Top Level Module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AssetsModule.forAssets(),
    SomeModule
  ]
})
export class MainModule{
  public ngDoBootstrap(ref: ApplicationRef){
    ref.bootstrap(StartupComponent);
  }
}

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(MainModuleNgFactory);
```

#### Some Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AssetsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(SOME_ROUTES, {useHash: true})
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  schemas:[
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
  bootstrap: [StartupComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Copying the Angular 2 `RouterModule.forChild()` pattern that they used for overrides. I have created a similar override structure for our `AssetsModule`

#### AssetsModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ImgDirective
  ],
  providers: [
    AssetService
  ]
})
export class AssetsModule{

  public static forAssets(...overrides: any[]): ModuleWithProviders{
    const providers = [{provide: ASSETS, multi: true, useValue: DefaultAssets}];
    providers.concat(overrides.map(override => {
      return {provide: ASSETS, multi: true, useValue: override};
    }));

    return {
      ngModule: AssetsModule,
      providers: providers
    };
  }
}
```

`ASSETS` is an `OpaqueToken`

This error, as unhelpful as it is, only occurs when the line `AssetsModule.forAssets()` is present in the top level module. If I comment it out or remove it the compilation succeeds.

Comment: I'm still not sure how exactly this part of AoT works. But have you tried to simplify `forAssets` contents to bare minimum to see what will happen? Notice that `forChild` you're referring to calls only `provideRoutes`, which is named exported function (as the error suggests), while `forAssets` has pretty much inside, including an anonymous arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your static function in the module class can only have 1 statement, and that statement has to be a `return`.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/tools/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/collector.ts#L54-L72

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing in a list of possible override types for `Assets` that you use to map back to dynamic overrides.

The AoT compiler does not allow us to build the list of providers dynamically like this. I think the only way to add any sort of logic when defining providers is by using a factory

Maybe you can re-architect your code to use a factory that determines which override to use.

```
    //factory function
    export function myFactory(override: WhichAssetToUse): any {
      if(override.type === 'type1'){
        return {a:1};// some override
      }
      return {b:1};// a different override
    }

    public static forAssets(whichAsset: WhichAssetToUse):ModuleWithProviders{

       providers:[
                 {provide: WhichAssetToUse, useClass: whichAsset},
                 {provide: Asset,
                 useFactory: myFactory,
                 deps: [WhichAssetToUse]}]

    }
```

`WhichAssetToUse` could be an abstract class or something that you inherit and pass in to the forAssets method.